# Printing out to terminal without it scrolling

Tags: java, c++, c

So I have been wondering how to do this for some time, and I thought who better to ask then the SO community.

I apologize in advance if this is a little vague, but I will do my best to get my question across.

We all remember the first time we got caught in a infinite loop with a print statement. The terminal fills up fast, and soon all you see it a bunch of scrolling text...

How do I make it not scroll? What I mean is ... How do I overwrite the line that has already been written.

How can I make my infinite loop with a one line print statement(no more than one new line) only print on one line. Where the terminal does not scroll.

```
Instead of ....
    This is an infinite loop
    This is an infinite loop
    This is an infinite loop

You just have one line that updates every iteration of the loop.
    This is an infinite loop
```

Thanks for reading, comment if this made absolutely no since. I'll try to clarify in a cloudy world...

PS - What I am doing right now is in C, but it wouldn't hurt to know how to do this in other languages.

## Question (0.1)

## What if you wanted to update multiple lines in place?

```
printf("This is some text\n");
printf("This is more text\n");
```

That would give me two lines and I want to update both of them, but not scroll.

Comment: what is OS your are using? can u tell me?

Comment: This is not specific to C/C++ is it specific to the terminal you happen to be using and how it is configured. Most terminals recognize the ANSI `'\r' character as moving the curser back to the beginning of the line without causing a new line (and hence not scrolling)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. That makes total since now that I think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need carriage return, not line feed hence you need to use only "\r"
Carriage return means bringing the cursor back to the beginning of the line.
Line feed means feeding a new line to the terminal.

In c :

```
while(1)
{
   printf("\r This is an infinite loop.");
}
```

Since the printf is buffered, therefore it's a good practice to explicitly flush the output stream.

Comment: You probably want to explicitly flush too... ?

Comment: @Tony D - Since the printf is buffered, therefore it's a good practice to explicitly flush the output stream.

Comment: I do actually know that, which is why I subtly hinted you might update your code accordingly... ;-).

Comment: What if I wanted more than one line?

Comment: If you want that line to start from next line, then you need to feed a new line to the terminal, and bring the cursor back at the beginning of the line. That's what '\n' does (line feed + carriage return).

Answer (score 3):

You may use the carriage return escape sequence, or `\r`. This will return the cursor to the start of the line.

```
while (1)
{
    std::cout << "\rTest.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
while(1)
{
  printf("this id infinite loop\n");
  sleep(1);
  system("clear");
}
```

Comment: +1 That's worthy of mention, but a lot less portable than `\r`.